# Links in Sharepoint to other Sharepoint Content

Tags: 2010, wiki, hyperlink

I am new to Sharepoint and am using Sharepoint 2010. I want have a page (should it be a list?) that contains quick links to other content that is already on the website. Is there a way to do this without hardcoding the fully qualified URI in the link?

For example, I want to have a link to a calendar we have. One strategy would be to make a link list and then add the URI as a new link: http://domain/Lists/Leave%20Calendar/calendar.aspx
This seems brittle since if anything changes the link will be broken. Is there anyway to use relative links? Should I not be using a list for this purpose? Any recommended approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a links list for this as well, relative links are supported in links lists.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Wiki Page or a Web Part Page, you can put a Summary Link Web Part on your page and author links from there. Here is the link to get started:

[Use and configure a Summary Link Web Part or a Summary Link field control](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/use-and-configure-a-summary-link-web-part-or-a-summary-link-field-control-HA010155168.aspx)

It refers to MOSS 2007 but most of the content is valid for SharePoint 2010.